# Flex 4 Modules Error #1009

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, module, flex4, migration

I'm upgrading my applications from flex 3 to flex 4.5 and encountered an error. It happened when a component was dynamically added into a module. The codes that can simulate the error have been extracted as below.

TestError.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.ModuleEvent;

        protected function ml_readyHandler(event:ModuleEvent):void
        {
            trace("Module finished loading");
            (ml.child as TestErrorModuleInterface).testTracing();
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:ModuleLoader id="ml" url="TestErrorModule.swf" ready="ml_readyHandler(event)"/>

</mx:Application>
```

TestErrorModule.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
       layout="absolute" width="100%" height="100%"
       implements="TestErrorModuleInterface">
<mx:Canvas id="_box">
    <mx:Label text="HERE IS MY TEST MODULE" x="142" y="133"/>
</mx:Canvas>

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        public function testTracing():void
        {
            trace("This is a method in the Test Module");
            var comp:TestErrorModuleComp = new TestErrorModuleComp();
            _box.addChild(comp);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

</mx:Module>
```

TestErrorModuleInterface.as

```
package {
public interface TestErrorModuleInterface {
        function testTracing():void;
    }
}
```

TestErrorModuleComp.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <mx:Label text="element" width="80" />

</mx:Canvas>
```

And this is the detailed error stacktrace:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at TestErrorModule/testTracing()[F:\MyEclipse_9_0\workspace\ViSR_Interface_Flex4\flex_src\TestErrorModule.mxml:16]
at TestError/ml_readyHandler()[F:\MyEclipse_9_0\workspace\ViSR_Interface_Flex4\flex_src\TestError.mxml:12]
at TestError/__ml_ready()[F:\MyEclipse_9_0\workspace\ViSR_Interface_Flex4\flex_src\TestError.mxml:17]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13128]
at mx.modules::ModuleLoader/moduleReadyHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\modules\ModuleLoader.as:465]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at ModuleInfoProxy/moduleEventHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\modules\ModuleManager.as:1149]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at ModuleInfo/readyHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\modules\ModuleManager.as:793]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/update()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\FlexModuleFactory.as:535]
at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/docFrameHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\FlexModuleFactory.as:681]
at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/docFrameListener()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\FlexModuleFactory.as:131]
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
       layout="absolute" width="100%" height="100%"
       implements="TestErrorModuleInterface">
<mx:Canvas id="_box">
    <mx:Label text="HERE IS MY TEST MODULE" x="142" y="133"/>
</mx:Canvas>

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        public function testTracing():void
        {
            trace("This is a method in the Test Module");
            if (initialized)
                addComp();
            else
                callLater(addComp);
        }

        private function addComp():void
        {
            var comp:TestErrorModuleComp = new TestErrorModuleComp();
            _box.addChild(comp);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

</mx:Module>
```

The problem is your `_box` isn't exist at the moment of module loading. You should wait module initialization first. `callLater()` here is an ugly first step. It is better to use component's invalidation then (in the process of refactoring).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the cause of the problem!